# Change ViewModel of some views in ASP.NET MVC causing error. How to fix?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, model, asp.net-mvc-5, viewmodel

There was a ViewModel named `HomeVM` with 7 models . I added a new ViewModel named `NewsVM` and cut 3 models in `HomeVM` and paste in `NewsVM`. 
I change everything to new ViewModel but I got this error :

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'NP1.ViewModels.NewsVM', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'NP1.ViewModels.HomeVM'.
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you update your view as well:

```
@model NP1.ViewModels.NewsVM
```

Comment: I'm sure I changed it  :/

Comment: Maybe you forgot to change it in some partial view that is called from the main view. This error means that you still have some view using the old `@model`.

Comment: Thank you dear ,Your right I used Layout with `@model NP1.ViewModels.HomeVM` . I should create a new Layout for this view ?! or are there another solution ?